# Products details problem with PayPal Express Checkout

Tags: paypal, checkout

After I redirect from my shopping cart to Paypal using `SetExpressCheckout` I can't see my product details on the left. I have the following code:

```
METHOD=SetExpressCheckout& 
VERSION=54.0&  
PWD=xxxxxxx&  
USER=xxxxxxx&  
SIGNATURE=xxxxxx&  
RETURNURL=xxxxxx&  
CANCELURL=xxxxxxx&  
PAYMENTACTION=Sale&  
AMT=20& 
SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole&  
LANDINGPAGE=Billing&  
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=Product+1a&  
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0=1&  
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=20.00&  
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=2&  
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0=descriere&  
ALLOWNOTE=1
```

Comment: ok, I solved it, after many hours: I changed the version to  63.0. :)

Comment: and also added 'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT' with the total price

Comment: Please answer your own question and mark it answered! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the version to 63.0 and also add 'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT' to the total price.